# Bound on maximum distance between points on a unit N-Sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

I want to select M points on the N-sphere such that $min_{i\neq j,i,j\in \{1..M\}} ||x_i - x_j||$ is maximized.

Are there good upper bounds for this max-min distance?

Comment: What do you consider "good"?

Comment: Better than the obvious ones (e.g. 2).  I basically just said good because the question without it is trivial.

Comment: See also http://neilsloane.com/packings/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the quantity in question $D(M, N),$ and let the volume of the spherical cap of dimension $N$ and radius $r$ $V(N, r),$normalized so that the volume of the whole sphere is $1.$ Since the caps of radius $2\arcsin D(M, N)/4$ are disjoint, you know that:

$$
M V(N,  2\arcsin D(M, N)/4) < 1.
$$
Since The function $V(N, r)$ is [well understood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), this gives you a bound.

Comment: I get the gist of your construction. Let me fiddle around with it a bit to see if I get a usable result from it.  Very elegant construction though.

Comment: This estimate can be improved using Boroczky's classic bound: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=512399